# How do I register my custom Environment Post Processor in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot

I followed the exact steps in this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners).

I have the following entries in my META-INF/spring.factories

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.mygroup.myapp.CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

My post processor:

```
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor
        implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {
..
}
```

I don't see anything in the logs as if it didn't get registered or not existing.

I unzipped the JAR and I can see META-INF/spring.factories. I can also see BOOT-INF/classes directly from the root.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no elegant way to solve this. You can make something like this :

```
@Component
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements
        EnvironmentPostProcessor, ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    private static final DeferredLog log = new DeferredLog();

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
            ConfigurableEnvironment env, SpringApplication app) {
        log.error("This should be printed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        log.replayTo(CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: That answer is correct. Some background: you don't "see anything" because the logging system hasn't been initialized yet. We can't initialize it at this point because we use the environment to configure it and you are customizing the environment.

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2.4, some optional constructor parameters have been added that provide built in access to deferred logging.   This answer might need to be updated.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html

Answer (score 4):

define spring.factories file

Environment Post Processor

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
class name with package
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot 2.4, there are now optional constructor parameters that provide access to deferred logs:

```
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private final Log log;

    public CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor(Log log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        log.info("CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor!!");
    }
}
```

NOTE: The log messages are *deferred* so they will appear in the log output only after the logging system has been initialized.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html